# How to remove this from picture in Jomsocial?

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

[image]

How to remove this features from my JomSocial? I don't know what is that but looking ugly. Thanks for answers

Comment: use css display:none for the class/id of the container(div/span)

Comment: doesn't work, any more idea?

Answer (score 2):

That's an untranslated language string.  Either you have an incomplete language file or the developers forgot to add the translation.  Contact the developers to help get your issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I translated by myself and added code in language file. This topic can be lock.